# Is there a way to check if my Vodafone number is still active?

Tags: cellphones, internet, mobile-operators

I am outside of India and got a Vodafone SIM while coming to US from India. I didn't register for International Roaming before leaving India, but I do plan to return for a visit in October this year.

How can I check if my number is still active? I do not see Vodafone network services on my phone, and I don't have my number registered on the Vodafone.in web site.

Comment: Can you call them and find out?

Comment: Have you tried calling your Vodafone number to see what happens?  What happens?

Comment: Thank you, I contacted the Vodafone care via email and they resolved my issue. They send me the instructions to check activation on my phone itself.

Answer (score 3):

If you remember which all proofs you have submitted during taking that sim from India, please share it with anyone(friends or relatives in India) and ask them to call the Vodafone customer care of your home town. If they could provide the valid information to customer care executives, you can know  whether your sim is active or not.

Comment: Thank you, I contacted the Vodafone care via email and they resolved my issue. They send me the instructions to check activation on my phone itself.

Comment: @RajTunwal could you post those instructions?

Comment: i got below instructions to update my phone settings:-          For Android Handset: -
Menu- Vodafone Service/Sim Tool Kit/STK- International Roaming- Select International- International Roaming will be on then select network manually & restart the device.
If problem not resolve, please check another device & share fresh feedback.
For I-Phone Handset:-
Menu- Setting- Phone- Sim Application- International Roaming- Select International- International Roaming will be on then select network manually & restart the device.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you set up voicemail, one of the easiest ways to establish if your line is active would be to call your number.  If you get your voicemail message, then all is well.

Also, assuming you set it up while you had the SIM on a network, you could log into the provider's web portal to see if the account is still active.  Usually this requires access to receiving SMS messaging, so if you have roaming disabled, you probably won't be able to enable this until you are in native coverage again.

Answer (score -2):

A SIM can get deactivated if it is not being used for more than 90 days. That is no outgoing or incoming calls/messages/internet access or any kind of VAS subscribed on that network. The only thing you can do is call 198 Toll free and enquire with the Vodafone authorities.

Comment: But I believe the SIM is outside of US, so there is not a way to call to 198.

Comment: Thank you, I contacted the Vodafone care via email and they resolved my issue. They send me the instructions to check activation on my phone itself.